# How directly connect to printer using ionic framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I  am trying to print order from our system through epos printer using Ionic V3 and I just want to print directly using my printer. without the help of external printer service like hp-printer google-cloud-printer

Is there any option to use the epos printer using Ionic Framework?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Starting with KitKat, most Android devices have print service plugins installed to enable printing using the Google Cloud Print and Google Drive services. Print service plugins from other printer manufactures are available through the App Store though the Google Cloud Print service plugin can also be used to print from an Android device to just about any printer type and model.

Comment: It is possible only when printer manufacturer releases an sdk for the ionic i have tested the epson sdk working good with cordova in ionic it is failing

Comment: @Madpop Thank you, I want know about the epos printer that support in ionic, can you suggest one

Comment: @Utpaul thanks for your reply.  Yes it support normal printer But I want to using epos printer. I want direct printing without using these service like google cloud and hp printer service

Comment: @MebinVarghese Then you need to write a custom plugin or ask the manufacturer whether he can provide any sdk support with out these it is not possbile

Comment: @Madpop  thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this? -> [Cordova Print Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer)
 connect the printer whit wifi scan and try to print

Comment: Thanks bro, I think this plugin is printing using with the help of printer service,